# How to debug script that makes the page run slowly (according to firefox)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, settimeout

I have a script that has a few timeouts, draws a menu using Raphael and uses all sorts of dynamic properties to accomplish this. You can take a look at it over at jsfiddle: [JSFiddle version of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/p9ujf/1/)

My problem is that Firefox, just occasionally, throws the "a script is running slowly etc." error when this page is open, might be after half a minute or more. Typically I'll have hovered over one element or so, so one sub menu is open at this time. The error usually doesn't point to any of my js files, sometimes even Firefox's own files.

How do I debug this, is it possible at all? Any tips are appreciated. (I'm using chronos for the timers now, didn't seem to help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Profile your code

You probably want to do *Profiling*, i.e. performance analysis of your code. As others have pointed out, Firebug is a good tool in Firefox. More specifically: In Firebug, click *Profile* in the *Console* tab. Then play with your navigation a bit and click *Profile* again to finish the analysis and get the results. They will tell you which functions were called how often and how long their execution took. This will help you identify performance bottlenecks in your code.

#### Optimize

On a quick glance I would say you could probably still optimize the DOM queries. Save references to the results of your expensive queries. And [use contexts](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip9) if possible, to make queries more efficient.

Also, [`requestAnimationFrame()`](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) seems to be the way to go for javascript animations now, instead of `setTimeout()`.

Comment: +1 for requestAnimationFrame(), I just can't wait for that to be available without a polyfill.

Comment: I have been using Firebug for a while, the profile function gave me no results though, which seemed odd to me. Maybe I'll fiddle more with it and see if I get it to work.

Comment: Just to make shure: Did you click the Profile button a second time at the end? It won't show any results before that.

Comment: I did, but I noticed later firebug says "No scripts found for this page". I have never seen that message before so I have no idea if it's a bug or what. All my scripts have a proper type set and is linkable from external sites and all.

Comment: Managed to sort it by restarting firefox, so I'll take a look at the profile now.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have a mechanism of some sort to allow users to stop "long running scripts".

How a script is deemed to be "long running" varies slightly between browsers, and is either the number of instructions executed within an 'execution context' or its elapsed duration.

JavaScript, when running in a browser, is predominantly event-driven (except for the immediate execution of JavaScript as the page is being parsed).  The browser will wait until an execution context has completed before doing anything, and any display refreshing etc can be blocked whilst waiting for JavaScript to execute.

You basically need to break up your instructions into responses to events.  If you have a massive loop anywhere (e.g. to do an animation), you really need to use an interval to break up the execution cycles.  E.g. `var interval = window.setInterval(refreshDisplay, 50);` - this will call a `refreshDisplay` function (with no arguments) every 50 milliseconds (a crude 20 calls-per-second).

Comment: I have been making scripts before where I had to have a timer to check if something happened. That created the same problem more frequently. What puzzles me now is that I can't see anything I've made which should be "polling" the browser. But I may not understand exactly how this script is processed, eventhough I know it's all in one thread. I think I shall try making breakpoints near my for/while loops.

Comment: ...but that's only if you have a massive loop.  And that would be an interval (repeat), not a timeout (delay), there's no _timer_.  Your fiddle doesn't reproduce your problem for me, although it does go weird if you hover over the menu items fast.

Comment: It only showed now and then for me as well, kept it open while doing other stuff. But that's why it's hard to spot, guess I'll just optimize a bit more in general and see if that fixes it. It shouldn't be weird if you hover it fast, that's what the delay is for, so that's strange. Edit: No wait, have forgotten to apply delay to points, only text, so thanks for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[**firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/) for debugging javascript (Firefox addon)

[image]

Use `F12` to show firebug

This will help you !

**With Firebug you can debug javascript with breakpoints and see all ajax calls !**

[image]

Comment: I've been using Firebug for a while, but where specifically would one put breakpoints when the firefox message appears after such a long time. After a mouse exit (which seems to me the latest function to be called)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Firebug` and use something like this as shown in screenshot --

[image: screenshot]

Link to download firebug --

http://getfirebug.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some operation that's running slowly, or one of your loops has a bad complexity. You can use binary splitting: remove half of your code, see if there's a dramatic increase in timing, and do the same in the half of the code that's running the slowest.

Comment: Yeah that could be a simple way of going about it. But the code doesn't appear to run slowly as it's running, that's the difficult part.